# Which one is issuer Certificate in chain

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, smartcard, x509, x509certificate2

When I receive chain,there are 3 certificates. I saw that issuerCert is chain[1],but my code works when I use chain[0] as issuer. I am using my CA card. Is it normal? Below code. FirmaXadesNet library. This function return ocspCerts as x509certificate[] ,

```
        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        chain.Build(cert);
        X509Certificate2 issuer = null;

        if (chain.ChainElements.Count > 1)
        {

            issuer = chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate;
            var client = chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate;

            var ocspCerts = ValidateCertificateByOCSP(unsignedProperties, client, issuer, ocspServers, digestMethod);

            if (ocspCerts != null)
            {
                X509Certificate2 startOcspCert = DetermineStartCert(ocspCerts);


                if (!EquivalentDN(startOcspCert.IssuerName, issuer.SubjectName))
                {
                    var chainOcsp = CertUtil.GetCertChain(startOcspCert, ocspCerts);
                    AddCertificate(chainOcsp.ChainElements[1].Certificate, unsignedProperties, true, ocspServers, crlList, digestMethod, ocspCerts);
                }

            }
```

AddCertificate(issuer, unsignedProperties, true, ocspServers, crlList, digestMethod, extraCerts);
}

private X509Certificate2[] ValidateCertificateByOCSP(UnsignedProperties unsignedProperties, X509Certificate2 client, X509Certificate2 issuer,
IEnumerable ocspServers, FirmaXadesNet.Crypto.DigestMethod digestMethod)
{
bool byKey = false;
List finalOcspServers = new List();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate clientCert = client.ToBouncyX509Certificate();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate issuerCert = issuer.ToBouncyX509Certificate();

```
        OcspClient ocsp = new OcspClient();

        string certOcspUrl = ocsp.GetAuthorityInformationAccessOcspUrl(issuerCert);           
       

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certOcspUrl))
        {
            finalOcspServers.Add(certOcspUrl);
        }

        foreach (var ocspUrl in ocspServers)
        {
            finalOcspServers.Add(ocspUrl);
        }

        foreach (var ocspUrl in finalOcspServers)
        {
            // original
            //byte[] resp = ocsp.QueryBinary(clientCert, issuerCert, ocspUrl);

            // ես եմ փոխել-> այ ստեղ նայել ուսումնասիրել
            byte[] resp = ocsp.QueryBinary(issuerCert,clientCert,ocspUrl);


            FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus status = ocsp.ProcessOcspResponse(resp);

            if (status == FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus.Revoked)
            {
                throw new Exception("Revoked certificate");
            }
            else if (status == FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus.Good)
            {
                Org.BouncyCastle.Ocsp.OcspResp r = new OcspResp(resp);
                byte[] rEncoded = r.GetEncoded();
                BasicOcspResp or = (BasicOcspResp)r.GetResponseObject();

                string guidOcsp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                OCSPRef ocspRef = new OCSPRef();
                ocspRef.OCSPIdentifier.UriAttribute = "#OcspValue" + guidOcsp;
                DigestUtil.SetCertDigest(rEncoded, digestMethod, ocspRef.CertDigest);

                ResponderID rpId = or.ResponderId.ToAsn1Object();
                ocspRef.OCSPIdentifier.ResponderID = GetResponderName(rpId, ref byKey);
                ocspRef.OCSPIdentifier.ByKey = byKey;

                ocspRef.OCSPIdentifier.ProducedAt = or.ProducedAt.ToLocalTime();
                unsignedProperties.UnsignedSignatureProperties.CompleteRevocationRefs.OCSPRefs.OCSPRefCollection.Add(ocspRef);

                OCSPValue ocspValue = new OCSPValue();
                ocspValue.PkiData = rEncoded;
                ocspValue.Id = "OcspValue" + guidOcsp;
                unsignedProperties.UnsignedSignatureProperties.RevocationValues.OCSPValues.OCSPValueCollection.Add(ocspValue);

                return (from cert in or.GetCerts()
                        select new X509Certificate2(cert.GetEncoded())).ToArray();
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("The certificate could not be validated");
    }
```

Comment: issuer of referenced certificate in `X509Chain` is always at index `[1]` when presented. You have to review parameters you use in external libraries.

Comment: but when I use index [0],I get ocspURL, otherwise no.

Comment: Issuer doesn't include its own OCSP server URL, it is included in leaf certificate which is at index `[0]`. I don't see any issues here.

Comment: And when OCSP server returns Revocation status - Good - everything is okay,yes ? Because when I use index [1] ,it returns status "Unknown".

Comment: Yes, you would want "good" status, of course.

Comment: Yes it's good.. But it's good for every Armenian ID card,but I need to get revoked status for those,which are not activated by Government.